# Resample a matlab array of uint8's

Tags: arrays, matlab, interpolation, resampling

I added a .JPG file to Matlab workspace, Matlab loaded it as a 2D array of 300x300 unsigned integers in range 0-255. 
I am interested in analyzing one of the rows of this matrix. For that purpose I simply extracted the row using

```
row = ones(300);
row = myMatrix(150, :);
```

Then, I realized that in order to compare it with another array, which is of length 450 elements, I need to expand my row vector by a factor of 1.5, i.e. stretch my array to 450 samples. For that purpose, I tried using resample function as follows :

```
row2 = resample(row, 3, 2);
```

But I received error saying that resample function does not support data of unit8 type.

Is there a way to achieve interpolation using resample in my case, or would you recommend another approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to convert image to double when you read it:

```
imgOriginal = imread('FileName.jpg');
imgDbl = double( imgOriginal );
% if you need you may also convert the image to [0..1] range
% imgDbl = double( imgOriginal ) / double( intmax(class(imgOriginal)) );
```

For resizing it is better to use `imresize`:

```
imgResized = imresize( imgDbl , 1.5, 'bilinear' ); % use the method you need
```

because for interpolating methods it will take into account rows above/below the one you need. Then you may select the right row

```
row = imgResized(150,:);
```

Comment: Resample gives error with double as well, says double not a supported type

Comment: @user3670482 Do you have a variable called `resample` in your workspace? This sounds like a potential variable shadowing.  Try doing `clear resample`, then try your code again with the image being casted as `double`.  BTW, I would also suggest you use `imresize`. This function is built specifically for resizing images.